# Laravel 5.4 - DB Query Assistance

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I am currently trying to write a query to display the value of 7 days worth of logs, which are automated into my table, for example the below data.

[image: DB Structure]

So what I am wanting is it to select the 7 newest entries in the posts (e.g. id 465-471) and then calculate them all together and spit out the number, e.g. 4353 for 7 latest enties of the above data.

The query I've written via SQL is as below:

```
SELECT SUM(posts) as poststw FROM (SELECT posts FROM `stats_log` ORDER BY dateline DESC LIMIT 7) tl
```

and this works successfully and manages to display via PhpMyAdmin the count correctly.

[image: Results from query]

I tried converting myself, and writing this in Laravel format as below, but it only ever displays 0 from the first line (to prevent page failing when query fails).

```
$posts_this_week = 0;
$posts_this_weeks = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT SUM(posts) as poststw FROM (SELECT posts FROM `stats_log` ORDER BY dateline DESC LIMIT 7) tl'));
```

Can anyone assist me in writing the correct query which shows the correct number, as I'm having a mental blank right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$posts_this_week = DB::table('stats_log')
                   ->orderBy('dateline','desc')
                   ->take(7)
                   ->get()
                   ->sum('posts');
```

Comment: That didn't quite work, as seen in the screenshot above it should display 4353, however the query written above outputs this SQL
`select sum(posts) as aggregate from stats_log limit 7` which shows 542427.

Comment: Exact same result - showing 542427 and again query output is as below `select sum(posts) as aggregate from stats_log limit 7`. It's like the limit is not working on it as 542427 is the full count of all cells, not just 7.

Comment: You can install `laravel-debugbar`, there is a db query string output. So you can know what exactly query have running on that line.

Comment: @DeepakKumarTP that edited one seemed to work! Thanks a million for your help!